# Facing issue with streamlit deployment

Tags: python-3.x, streamlit, google-gemini

I am trying to deploy my app via streamlit, which uses Google Gemini API. It was working fine locally, but tends to throw the following error.

```
google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: This app has encountered an error. The
original error message is redacted to prevent data leaks. Full error details have been
recorded in the logs (if you're on Streamlit Cloud, click on 'Manage app' in the lower
right of your app).

File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptrunner/script_runner.py", line 535, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "/mount/src/imagegem/image_gem.py", line 46, in <module>
    answer =  promopt(prompt, processed_image)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/mount/src/imagegem/image_gem.py", line 12, in promopt
    response = model.generate_content([prompt, img])
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/generativeai/generative_models.py", line 232, in generate_content
    response = self._client.generate_content(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/ai/generativelanguage_v1beta/services/generative_service/client.py", line 566, in generate_content
    response = rpc(
               ^^^^
File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py", line 131, in __call__
    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/api_core/retry/retry_unary.py", line 293, in retry_wrapped_func
    return retry_target(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/api_core/retry/retry_unary.py", line 153, in retry_target
    _retry_error_helper(
File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/api_core/retry/retry_base.py", line 212, in _retry_error_helper
    raise final_exc from source_exc
File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/api_core/retry/retry_unary.py", line 144, in retry_target
    result = target()
             ^^^^^^^^
File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/api_core/timeout.py", line 120, in func_with_timeout
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 78, in error_remapped_callable
    raise exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc) from exc
```

Note: I have already added the API key in the github repo secret.